# paint method adding white layer to Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This code should create a black window, and then add a line and polygon over it.

```
public class gui extends JFrame {

 JPanel pane = new JPanel();
 gui(String title){
    super(title);
    setBounds(100,100,500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container con = this.getContentPane();
    pane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    con.add(pane);
    setVisible(true);
 }

 public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.drawLine(100, 100, 400, 400);

    Point p1 = new Point(400, 100);
    Point p2 = new Point(100, 300);
    Point p3 = new Point(200, 400);

    int[] xs = { p1.x, p2.x, p3.x };
    int[] ys = { p1.y, p2.y, p3.y };
    Polygon triangle = new Polygon(xs, ys, xs.length);

    g.setColor(new Color(250,0,0));
    g.fillPolygon(triangle);
 }
}
```

When I delete the `paint()` method, a plain black GUI is created, as expected.

However, when the `paint()` method is in place, you get the line and polygon **over a white background**, not a black background.

How can I make the black background show through?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Don't extend components unless adding functionality. 3) Don't override `paint` in a top-level container, instead use `paintComponent` in a panel, or better still, use.. 4) A `BufferedImage` to be displayed in a label. 5) Don't call `setBounds` on the GUI, instead set the size of the content and `pack()` the GUI to get the right size accounting for frame borders etc. 6) `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: use paintComponent, otherwise you're risking performace of Graphics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call

```
super.paint(g);
```

in your `paint` method.

In Swing the preferred approach is to override `paintComponent` although since `JFrame` is not actually a `JComponent` this method will not be called. To use this approach, the functionality could be moved to a custom `JComponent` instead.

Comment: Also, be sure to check the [interesting article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#swing_summary) from Oracle (which looks terrible with the new style...)

Comment: *"Also better to use paintComponent for Swing components."*  ..and the override notation, which will cheerfully inform you that a `JFrame` has no `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  ;)

Comment: Any chance one of you can elaborate on the structure I would use if I used the paintComponent approach?

Comment: See this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JPanelpaintComponentGraphicsg.htm)

Comment: @ACarter Don't override the `paint` methods of top level containers, use a custom component like `JComponent` or `JPanel` instead, the override the `paintComponent` method of that. You might like to have a read of [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Incidentaly, @MadProgrammer, what's the advatage of such a method (apart from frazzling my brain further ;))?

Comment: @ACarter Top level containers aren't double buffered and don't provide as many opportunities to painting within the layers, such as `paintComponent` from `JComponent`. By convention, you shouldn't be extending from the likes of JFrame or JDialog as, in most cases, you are not actually adding functionality to this containers, but just using them...IMHO